# Generic class in java

Tags: java

*this is a generic class*

```
public class Samplevehicle <t > 
{

    public void type(t obj)
    {

        if(obj instanceof Vechicle)
        {   

            System.out.println("BIke or truck");
        }
        else if(obj instanceof Bike)
        {   

            System.out.println("BIKE");
        }
        else if(obj instanceof Truck)
        {
            System.out.println("Truck");
        }
    }

}
```

*//superclass*

```
public class Vechicle {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("TYPES");
        Samplevehicle<Vechicle>sv=new Samplevehicle<Vechicle>();

        sv.type(new Vechicle());

        Samplevehicle<Truck>t=new Samplevehicle<Truck>();
        t.type(new Truck());

        Samplevehicle<Bike>b=new Samplevehicle<Bike>();
        b.type(new Bike(1));


    }

}
```

*//subclass*

```
public class Bike extends Vechicle

{
    public Bike(int id) {

    }
}
```

//2nd subclass

```
public class Truck extends Vechicle
{


    *//truck extending vechicle*

}
```

*//Even im passing the object of subclass its showing superclass 
 object*

Comment: You'll want to ask an actual and specific and answerable question

Comment: What do you mean by "generic"?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `else`s:

```
if(obj instanceof Vechicle)
{   

    System.out.println("BIke or truck");
}
if(obj instanceof Bike)
{   

    System.out.println("BIKE");
}
if(obj instanceof Truck)
{
    System.out.println("Truck");
}
```

As it stands, you're checking if `obj` is *not* an `instanceof Vehicle` but *is* an `instanceof Bike`, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I feel you are trying to print whether the object is belongs to specific class (or) not. If that is the case, use getClass() than instanceof (an object is a instance of same class and all other super classes, and the interfaces that it implements). Try using getClass() to get specific results.

```
  public void type(t obj)
        {

            if(obj.getClass().equals(Vechicle.class))
            {   

                System.out.println("BIke or truck");
            }
            else if(obj.getClass().equals(Bike.class))
            {   

                System.out.println("BIKE");
            }
            else if(obj.getClass().equals(Truck.class))
            {
                System.out.println("Truck");
            }
        }
```